# Метод Монте-Карло код

Tags: javascript, любой-язык

Пожалуйста, если у кого-то есть код (любой язык программирования), как узнавать, пересекается ли отрезок/луч с кубом в пространстве? У меня есть код, но он возвращает true, если начало отрезка или конец отрезка находится в кубе. Сам пишу на JS, но пофиг на каком языке напишите - конвертирую. Заранее спасибо!

P.S. Значения передаваемые в функцию: все точки куба (ax,ay,az,bx,by,bz...), начало точки отрезка, нормированный вектор направления отрезка, конечная точка отрезка. Если у вас свои аргументы, то не стесняйтесь - пишите, че-нибудь придумаю.

Comment: Я не стесняясь предполагаю что этот вопрос будет закрыт

Comment: Чем Вас не устраивает ваш код? Приведите код, а мы посмотрим.

Comment: Сейчас напишу. (Если не закроют до этого)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Смотрите. Вам нужно по существу пересечение отрезка (возможно, бесконечного) с полупространством.

Отрезок можно задавать как

```
class Segment
{
    Axis axis;
    double begin, end; // может быть infinity
                       // координаты начала и конца на оси
}

class Axis
{
    Point origin;
    UnitVector direction;

    double getCoord(Point p)
    {
        return Tools.ScalarProduct(p - origin, direction);
    }
}
```

Теперь, полупространство

```
class HalfSpace
{
    Axis normal;         // произвольная точка на границе +
                         // ортогональный вектор в сторону,
                         // принадлежащую полупространству

    double isIn(Point p)
    {
        return normal.getCoord(p) > 0;
    }
}
```

Пересечение с осью в координатах на оси:

```
Segment intersection(Axis axis, HalfSpace hs)
{
    var S = hs.normal.origin;
    var O = axis.origin;
    var l = axis.direction;
    var n = hs.normal.direction;
    // пусть X точка пересечения, тогда X = O + alpha * l
    // и XS * n = 0 => (S - (O + alpha * l)) * n = 0 =>
    // (S - O) * n = alpha * (l * n)
    var r = Tools.ScalarProduct(l, n);
    if (r == 0) return null; // прямая и плоскость параллельны
    var l = Tools.ScalarProduct(S - O, n);
    var alpha = l / r;
    var X = O + alpha * l;
    // тестируем, в какую сторону смотрит полупространство
    var positive = r > 0;
    var begin = positive ? alpha : double.NegaiveInfinity;
    var end = positive ? double.PositiveInfinity : alpha;
    return new Segment() { axis = axis, begin = begin, end = end };
}

Segment intersection(Segment s, HalfSpace hs)
{
    double s1 = intersection(s.axis, hs);
    if (s1 == null) return null;
    var begin = min(s.begin, s1.begin);
    var end = min(s.end, s1.end);
    return new Segment() { axis = s.axis, begin = begin, end = end };
}
```

Теперь просто представляете куб как пересечение 6 полупространств.

Answer (score 2):

Метод Монте-Карло?

Вот пересечение луча и куба, там в трассировщиках лучей их полно.

```
// r.dir.(x,y,z) направляющий вектор. 
x = 1.0f / r.dir.x;
y = 1.0f / r.dir.y;
z = 1.0f / r.dir.z;
//lb(left-bottom) левая нижняя точка куба, rt(right-top) правая верхняя и.т.д.
//r.org(x,y,z) начальная точка луча.  
float t1 = (lb.x - r.org.x)*x;
float t2 = (rt.x - r.org.x)*x;
float t3 = (lb.y - r.org.y)*y;
float t4 = (rt.y - r.org.y)*y;
float t5 = (lb.z - r.org.z)*z;
float t6 = (rt.z - r.org.z)*z;

float tmin = max(max(min(t1, t2), min(t3, t4)), min(t5, t6));
float tmax = min(min(max(t1, t2), max(t3, t4)), max(t5, t6));

// Не пересекает, куб за лучом
if (tmax < 0)
{
    t = tmax;
    return false;
}

// Не пересекает
if (tmin > tmax)
{
    t = tmax;
    return false;
}

t = tmin;
return true;
//t расстояние от точки луча до первого столкновения.
```

Подразумевается система координат связанная с кубом.

[Вот этот GameDev тред еще имеет смысл посмотреть](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/18436/most-efficient-aabb-vs-ray-collision-algorithms)